# Interesting Objective-c method behavior

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, overriding

Why does the call to `_something` from `foo` call B's implementation of `_something`?

```
@interface A
@end

@implementation A
- (void) _something {
    NSLog(@"A");
}
- (void) foo {
    [self _something];
}
@end

@interface B : A
@end

@implementation B
- (void) _something {
        NSLog(@"B");
}
@end
```

Comment: what is `foo`?  an `A` object or a `B` object?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann `foo` is a message that class `A` responds to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only calls `B`'s implementation if it is called for object of `B` class.
This is because in objective-C, all methods are "virtual" (although this is a considerable simplification), basically due to its [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

To be more correct, Objective-C has no methods. Instead, you send "messages" to objects. It is handled in runtime and object itself decides how to "respond" to this message. By default, it looks up the selector in its class and calls the associated "method" (which in case of `_something` is different for A and B).

Answer (score 2):

It'll do that if you call -foo on an instance of B, because B overrides the -_something method.

Method dispatch is implemented in Objective-C by message sending, so the foo method sends a message to the receiver telling it to do _something. The receiver (or the runtime on the receiver's behalf) looks up what it's supposed to do in response to any message; the message specifies a method *selector* and the object executes the corresponding *implementation*. There is a different implementation of _something for the classes A and B.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is a `B`, you called `_something`, so you get the code for `B`'s `_something`. If you were expecting `A`'s implementation, you're misunderstanding objective-C message passing. The code for the method is determined at runtime. If you come from C++, imagine all the methods are virtual.

Answer (score 1):

If you called `_something` on an object of class `B`, then you've essentially overridden it:

```
B *myClass = [B alloc] init];
[myClass _something];
```

**Output:**

```
B
```

Had you done the following example, you will not have overriden `_something` and you get class `A`'s output:

```
A *myClass = [A alloc] init];
[myClass _something];
```

**Output:**

```
A
```

It really depends on the class from which you've instantiated your object due to the dynamic nature of messages:

```
A *myClass = [B alloc] init];
[myClass _something];
```

**Output:**

```
B
```